# Redirect googlebot from my ajax page to static html page

Tags: php, ajax, redirect, googlebot

My main page call is '`www.xxxx/!#/hear-us`'
I want to redirect the crawler to html version call hear-us.php
I used

```
<?php 
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Googlebot")) { 
        header('Location: http://xxxx/hear-us.php');
    } 
?>
```

When the url is submitted to Google web master, it does not see the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add the actual redirect code in the header you're sending either by sending the Status header before the Location one or with:

```
header("Location: /foo.php", TRUE, 301);
```

Note, this is a permanent redirect, change the code as needed.

Also, a good practice is to call `exit` as soon as you send the headers, otherwise any output may modify (or garble) the message.